# What concerns should I have when using special character symbols on the web?

Tags: html, css, fonts, special-characters, accessibility

In our web app, we're using colored stars (★ aka `&#9733;`) to represent a rating. So the first four stars would be a solid color while the last star would be white to represent a rating of 4 out of 5. Like so:

> [image]

- What concerns does this raise in terms of accessibility and support?
- I can't be certain that the version of the font in the user's browser supports this character, what are some methods to provide "graceful degradation" to this? Or is the coverage good enough that this is not an issue?
- How is this "rendered" by a screenreader? Would wrapping the rating with a `<span title="4 out of 5">` provide more accessibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general question in the heading is very broad. To address it briefly, the main concern is font problems, which can be rather serious, and there is really no graceful degradation; for a longer answer, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

The specific question about colored stars is much simpler, and the short answer is that there are strong reasons for using five images, each with a different number of colored stars. Then you can use meaningful `alt` attributes, like `alt="four stars"`, and things work rather reliably. They should be content images (via `img`), as there is no way to specify textual alternative to a background image.

Considering the possibility of using the BLACK STAR “★” character, its [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/fontsupport.htm) is not particularly bad but not very widespread either. There is no simple way to find out the percentage of computers that have some font containing it. Moreover, if the character exists in some font(s) in the system, its appearance may vary a lot. For this specific character, glyphs can be expected to look rather similar – but in different sizes.

If your context really required the use of a symbol as a *text character*, then you may need to take risks, but here the symbols accompany text instead of really being contained in text, so it’s OK to use images.

Using an embedded font via `@font-face` is possible but sounds overkill here.

Screen readers vary a lot in their treatment of special characters. In general, they have been designed to read normal text in some human language(s), and they often fail to speak special characters meaningfully – or at all, even by simply saying the name of the character. The `title` attribute may be spoken, but usually as an option only, and the user may be unaware of the existence of such options.

Images cause some HTTP requests, but this is of marginal or ignorable impact. (You could use CSS sprites, though that’s hardly useful in a simple case like this.) The images typically get cached well. They can be scaled to match text size if desired, e.g. by setting the height of `img` elements in `em` units (and not setting width, so that they get scaled so that width:height ratio is preserved).

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer. +1 to not relying upon the `title` attribute to be announced. I agree that using an image would be better than symbols. A background image (sprited) could also be used with appropriate text ("four out of five stars") and image replacement - that's the technique I'd probably use.

Answer (score 0):

For best overall compatibility use an image. You know what it will look like, the accessibility concerns are straightforward, and you don't need to worry about browser support for various features.

Comment: I suppose I may be trying to be overly clever, but I think images have some drawbacks (extra http requests, poor flexibility/scalability, and would be more cumbersome to tweak the styling of). I'm hoping there's some specific info to validate/alleviate my concerns.

Comment: I agree with Jukka that the HTTP request is marginal and will be cached most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't want to experiment, you should follow [Jukkas advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13039348/1591669) and use an `img` element.

If, for whatever reason, you want to use the Unicode star symbols, you'd have to try to make it accessible. According to your description, I guess you currently do something like this:

```
<div class="rating">
  <span>★★★★</span>★
</div>

<!-- CSS: .rating span {color:yellow;} -->
```

This example **doesn't** mark-up the semantics of the rating, and therefor screenreaders and other user-agents can't "understand" (announce) the meaning of it. The rating score is only described by color → this is not accessible.

A possible way *might* be the use of the [`abbr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-abbr-element.html#the-abbr-element), however, this use case could stretch the definition too far ("Are the five stars really an abbreviation of a rating score?"):

```
<div class="rating">
  <abbr title="rating of 4 out of 5"><span>★★★★</span>★</abbr>
</div>

<!-- CSS: .rating span {color:yellow;} -->
```

Comment: One issue with this is that behavior of reading the abbr title instead of content is an *option* in some screenreaders that is often off by default.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a @font-face from font squirrel.  If the rating will never change, then how about creating an image using Photoshop or similar program to use as a background image? The title for the span is not a good one.  What happens if you later change the rating, then you have to go change all the title attributes.  I would make a more general title like "Rating".  If the rating isn't absolutely necessary for your content on the page, consider using JavaScript to display the rating.  That way, you don't actually change the HTML, therefore your security concerns should be handled.

Comment: The rating html snippet is dynamically generated from data, so I have no concerns with having to maintain the title text. For our uses, the rating is important information, and js is not out of the question but for this situation, I don't believe should be necessary.

Comment: Amazon.com uses sprite images to display their rating stars.  I would say if they aren't worried about the security concerns, it should work just fine for you.  I would use a background image.  This is the best solution.  You want to separate the presentation/behavior from your content.  I don't think that the 4 out of 5 stars image is important content for your users.  If what you want displayed on the page doesn't add value to your users, then you need to separate that content from the main content on your pages using either CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Disagree that the star rating isn't important information that should be accessible to all users - including those who are visually impaired. Using a background image is fine, but use an image replacement technique to visually hide the text ("four out of five stars")